# Translate names of the month

Tags: php, datetime, datetime-format

I am using OOP PHP DateTime and I want to post month name in three letters like so

```
$EventDate = new DateTime(DATEDATA);
echo $EventDate -> format('M');
```

This is code for what I need, but for example if the DATEDATA will be december it will echo out DEC but I want this DEC to translate in my language and instead of `DEC` to echo `დეკ`.
Can someone explain how it is possible how to translate this kind of things manually?

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: manually - `$TranslateArray[$EventDate->format('n') - 1]`

Answer (score 4):

The [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/class.intldateformatter) class contains the [`IntlDateFormatter::formatObject()`](http://php.net/intldateformatter.formatobject) method, which offers a quick way of formatting a `DateTime` object using a specified locale.

As an example, let's format a `DateTime` object for *December 12th, 2017* as an abbreviated month name in Georgian.

```
$datetime = new DateTime("2017-12-12");
$month = IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($datetime, "MMM", "ka");
echo $month;
```

The above example outputs the following, as expected:

```
დეკ
```

Comment: I am trying exactly same code and it is not outputting დეკ , it writes following error:
FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: DATETIME::__CONSTRUCT(): FAILED TO PARSE TIME STRING (GET_FIELD('EVENT_DATE')) AT POSITION 0 (G): THE TIMEZONE COULD NOT BE FOUND IN THE DATABASE IN /APP/PUBLIC/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/AXALI/FRONT-PAGE.PHP:30 STACK TRACE: #0 /APP/PUBLIC/WP-CONTENT/THEMES/AXALI/FRONT-PAGE.PHP(30): DATETIME->__CONSTRUCT('GET_FIELD('EVEN...') #1 /APP/PUBLIC/WP-INCLUDES/TEMPLATE-LOADER.PHP(74): INCLUDE('/APP/PUBLIC/WP-...') #2 /APP/PUBLIC/WP-BLOG-HEADER.PHP(19): REQUIRE_ONCE('/APP/PUBLIC/WP-...')...

Comment: The comments system is not the right place to debug your code, sorry.